# R: if else statement is handling column as whole vector

Tags: r, tidyquant

I have a data set where I want to calculate the 6 month return of stocks with `tq_get` (see example below)

Dataset called `top`

```
ticker 6month
AKO.A
BIG
BGFV
```

Function

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyquant)
library(riingo)

calculate <- function (x) {
  (tq_get(x, get = "tiingo", from = yesterday, to = yesterday)$adjusted/tq_get(x, get = "tiingo", from = before, to = before)$adjusted)-1
}

top[2] <- lapply(top[1], function(x) calculate(x))
```

Unfortunately for some of the tickers there is no value existing which results in error message when simply using `lapply` or `mutate` as the resulting vector is smaller (less rows) then the existing dataset. Resolving with `try_catch` did not worked.

I now wanted to apply a work around by checking with `is_supported_ticker()` provided by the package `riingo` if the ticker is available

```
calculate <- function (x) {
  if (is_supported_ticker(x, type = "tiingo") == TRUE) {
  (tq_get(x, get = "tiingo", from = yesterday, to = yesterday)$adjusted/tq_get(x, get = "tiingo", from = before, to = before)$adjusted)-1
  }
  else {
    NA
  }
}

top[2] <- lapply(top[1], function(x) calculate(x))
```

But now I receive the error message `x ticker must be length 1, but is actually length 3`.

I assume this is based on the fact that the whole first column of my dataset is used as input for `is_supported_ticker()` instead of row by row. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glancing at the documentation, it looks like `tq_get` supports multiple symbols, only `if_supported_ticker` goes one at a time. So probably you should check all the tickers to see if they are supported, and then use `tq_get` once on all the supported ones. Something like this (untested, as I don't have any of these packages):

```
calculate <- function (x) {
  supported = sapply(x, is_supported_ticker, type = "tiingo")
  result = rep(NA, length(x))
  result[supported] = 
    (
      tq_get(x[supported], get = "tiingo", from = yesterday, to = yesterday)$adjusted / 
      tq_get(x[supported], get = "tiingo", from = before, to = before)$adjusted
    ) - 1
  return(result)
}
```

It worries me that `before` and `yesterday` aren't function arguments - they're just assumed to be there in the global environment. I'd suggest passing them in as arguments to `calculate()`, like this:

```
calculate <- function (x, before, yesterday) {
  supported = sapply(x, is_supported_ticker, type = "tiingo")
  result = rep(NA, length(x))
  result[supported] = 
    (
      tq_get(x[supported], get = "tiingo", from = yesterday, to = yesterday)$adjusted / 
      tq_get(x[supported], get = "tiingo", from = before, to = before)$adjusted
    ) - 1
  return(result)
}

# then calling it
calculate(top$ticker, before = <...>, yesterday = <...>)
```

This way you can pass values in for `before` and `yesterday` on the fly. If they are objects in your global environment, you can simply use `calculate(top$ticker, before, yesterday)`, but it gives you freedom to vary those arguments without redefining those names in your global environment.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm (only one typo in line 6 where supported is missing on "p"). I calculate `yesterday` and `before` before as values in the global environment. How to pass them as arguments to the function?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! And typo fixed. I'll edit to include a version with `before` and `yesterday` arguments.

Comment: Great, perfect.